# How do I clean a sankey pump?

Tags: techniques, equipment, kegging, cleaning

What is the best way to clean a sankey pump it after I use it so it doesn't get moldy inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and pasted from [doityourself.com](http://www.doityourself.com/stry/cleaning-a-keg-tap-stepbystep)

> To begin cleaning the tap you will
>   need to get keg tap detergent and mix
>   it with water.    Check with your
>   local liquor store to see if they
>   carry a cleaning kit for a tap. The
>   instructions on the kit will be able
>   to tell you how much cleaning
>   detergent and water needs to be mixed
>   together. The mixture should be put
>   into some sort of bottle that has a
>   hand pump to produce the cleaning
>   solution.
>
> Find the tap's faucet and remove the
>   knob. Once you have done that, you
>   will need to put the knob, the faucet
>   and the hose that produces the beer,
>   into a bucket.
>
> Find the cleaning attachment in your
>   kit and connect it to the faucet. Take
>   the bucket with the other parts in it
>   and place it under the main part of
>   the keg. Then put the hose inside the
>   bucket so the cleaning solution will
>   be able to steam into the bucket.
>
> You are now ready to pump the cleaning
>   solution into the bucket. It is best
>   to let the solution sit in the hose
>   for a good amount of time to make sure
>   that all bacteria is broken down. Your
>   kit will tell you how long to soak the
>   hose.
>
> Take the bottle you used to pump the
>   detergent and clean it thoroughly.
>   Fill it with cold water (without any
>   detergent) and pump the entire bottle
>   of water into the hose. Use the other
>   tools included in your kit, such as a
>   wrench to unscrew the facuet and use
>   the brush to clean out the keg and the
>   faucet.
>
> Rinse all the materials with cold
>   water and allow them to dry completely
>   before reassembling the unit.
>
> Now that your keg tap is clean, it can
>   be put into storage to await your next
>   party.